# Android 11 - E/chromium: [ERROR:context_group.cc(455)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: too few uniforms or varyings supported

Tags: android, android-emulator

I got this error on log console for Android 11 emulator.

E/chromium: [ERROR:context_group.cc(455)] ContextResult::kFatalFailure: too few uniforms or varyings supported.

I tried to load Html data on Webview.

webview.loadData( "some html data", "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8")

But it doesn't render and shows blank screen & throws above error

Look forward for your help.

Comment: I observed once successfully webview rendered and tried to render / invoke again I observed this error'

Comment: I also faced this error with a white screen. Any solution you have?